# Delete duplicate rows and add first column to original row Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, duplicates, copy-paste

I've been trying to look on the internet for a piece of code or a direction that could help me solve this issue.
Basically, I have a set of data over four columns where in the latest column a description is given on what the data is representing.
I am importing new data everyday where the description could be the same but a different set of data is given which are just numbers.
Now I would like my script to find the duplicates, take the data and add that to the original data and remove the duplicate.
So, I only want to accumulate column one and delete the rest of the data.

I'm aware of how to find duplicates, delete the entire set of data and push the new set of data without duplicates to the sheet.
However, I cannot find any possibility for this online. It is probably a possibility to get the values of a range in the var Newdata copy that to the row where the duplicate is found and then push that array in its entirety.
However, everything i've tried to incorporate that gives me multiple bugs and infinite calculation times.

I hope someone can help me with this.

```
function DuplicateRemoval(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function overwriteWithNew() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];

  data.forEach(function(row, rowI) {
    if (!newData.some(function(row2) {return row[0] === row2[0];})) { // If the key is not in the output yet
      for (var row2I = data.length - 1; row2I >= rowI; row2I--) {     // Then, starting from the last column
        if (data[row2I][0] === row[0]) {                              // Find the latest data with the same key
          newData.push(data[row2I]);                                  // Add it to the output
          break;                                                      // And continue with the next row
        }
      }
    }
  });
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);   
}
```

Comment: Hi Robin, Thank you so much. So for example if my duplicate description is in column 5 and my data that I want to SUM is in column 1 is that possible in this script? It looks like this one is checking only one column and adds that same column together, is that correct?

Comment: Ah, now I understand, this can just as well be done with `=QUERY(A:E, "SELECT E, SUM(A) WHERE E <> ''GROUP BY E")` Do you want the format to change? If not what happens to columns 2-4?

Comment: I just changed my data again, where currently Col C contains a description that will be duplicated and Col D and E are values that need to be summed up when there is a duplication. I've never worked with Query before can I just put that query in any cell in the sheet? Thanks

Comment: Can you please post an example workbook to show your structure and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Robin. I currently use the SUMIF() formula in the script that adds all the values with the same description together and I then let the script execute the duplicate removal part. Works like a charm. Thanks for your input!